# Ubuntu 16.04 Network Problem & Shutdown Problem

Tags: networking, shutdown, reinstall

I have laptop HP 635 with Atheros AR5B195 network chipset. I was using Ubuntu 16.04 for several months with no problems, but suddenly it could not be turned off. It freezed at the "shutdown screen" (the dots on purple background) so I turned it of by holding the power button. And after I turn it on again, it was impossible to use internet. It shows that "No Network Device Available". So I reinstall the system but both problems (shutdown and network) persist. I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 and then Win7, but these problems were still there.
I would be grateful for any advice. Thanks.